# Testimonial Slider — Testimonial Text Not Wrapping

Tags: css, wordpress, slider, word-wrap, testimonials

I'm working on a site for a client and Im trying to use testimonial slider but for the life of me I cannot figure out why the text won't wrap.

here is the link: https://adventuretoward.com/client/chad/

Comment: As i've seen you posted other questions here on SO in the same manner. You got comments on them asking you to add code to your questions not only a ' story ' and an external link to the website. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: It's a wordpress plugin...I dont have any code I've added to it... just trying to figure out what in the plugin code is off.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask questions properly as was mentioned above. A good question is half the answer.
About your case: the `<p>` with testimonial is a child of a `<pre>` and `<pre>` has a default of [`white-space: pre;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).

I see a misuse of a `pre` tag, however you can just add `white-space: normal;` to your paragraph like this:

```
.testimonials {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

Comment: Hey — I appreciate you! Ill try to formulate better questions in the future. Do you have an example of how I should do this when it seems to be a plugin issue / I can't find which code element is causing my issue?

Comment: @MeghanLogue, I believe you can edit your css at your.site/wp-admin/theme-editor.php, try to add `.testimonials {white-space: normal;}` or `.testimonials {white-space: normal !important;}` at the end of the file called `style.css` or `main.css` or `custom.css`.

Comment: oop - sorry I meant how I should ask a good question in the future!

Comment: @MeghanLogue, generally, it is your task to isolate the problem and narrow down the code that responsible for it. We are glad to help, but we aren't gonna do your job. If you're a beginner in web development, to learn the basics is your best shot. You will be able to ask a good question then as well as to solve such a simple problem by yourself. If you're just trying to manage your own site, and you see an issue with a wp plugin, you can ask its author for help. It might be that you found a bug, this way you'll help a lot of future users. Good luck.